# Adding an image to Live Tile Notifications

Tags: image, notifications, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, live-tile

I'm currently working on live tile notifications for my Universal App.  I'm running into an issue where the wide tile is not showing anything, but the small tile is working fine; can anyone point me in the right direction of why my wide tile isn't showing anything correctly?  It works fine with just a text-based tile (i.e. TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150Text03).

Thank you!  Below is my code to push notifications.

```
foreach (var item in temp)
        {
            XmlDocument tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileWide310x150PeekImage06);

            var title = item.Title;
            string titleText = title.Text == null ? String.Empty : title.Text;
            tileXml.GetElementsByTagName(textElementName)[0].InnerText = titleText;

            XmlNodeList wideTileImageAttrib = tileXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");

            ((XmlElement)wideTileImageAttrib[0]).SetAttribute("src", "http://i.imgur.com/DjooITV.jpg");
            ((XmlElement)wideTileImageAttrib[0]).SetAttribute("alt", "Image");

            Debug.WriteLine(tileXml.ToString());

            // Create a new tile notification. 
            updater.Update(new TileNotification(tileXml));

            tileXml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Text04);

            tileXml.GetElementsByTagName(textElementName)[0].InnerText = titleText;

            Debug.WriteLine(tileXml.ToString());

            // Create a new tile notification. 
            updater.Update(new TileNotification(tileXml));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to answer my own question, and state that the image I was trying to add is simply too large for the tile to handle.  To anyone that stumbles upon this question, resize your images appropriately in code to make sure they display properly.